# Will there be many sandbox related questions on certification 70-488?

Tags: sandbox-solution, certification

According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?id=70-488) Microsoft article on the 70-488 certification test for SharePoint 2013 there will be several question regarding the creation of sandbox solutions, despite the (still debated) deprecated status of said solutions.

Could anyone shed some light on this? Am I expected to learn all about sandbox solutions for the test? I could see a point in it, as I imagine there being quite a few sandbox which I'd be expected to be able to handle in a work situation.

Comment: One reason is of course legacy. Another is that Apps are effectively run in a Sandboxed solution, so the technology is present even in 2013

Comment: Of course, it's just that the two books I've read/browsed so far on SP2013 talks about sandbox solutions for about half a page each. They just tell you that they exist, and not to use them.